# Nested 'For' cycle required

Tags: vba, excel

I have four cells in an Excel workbook:

```
A1  
A2  
A3  
A4
```

A1 and A2 cells include starting values such as `5` and `7`. A3 has an formula and evaluates a result using A1 and A2's values. A4 cell has a target value. An iterational operation continue up to A3 cell's value equal to A4's 0,0001 approximation. For each A1's differential increment A2 will change depending on its range.

Can anybody help me with VBA including nested 'For' cycles?

My sample workbook:
[image: My sample workbook]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an add-in with excel that is built to do this, it's called the solver addin.

There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/solver.html) that explains how it works.